# Can i pass an Instance of a FragmentActivity into a Fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I’m trying to do a tab layout, but before I’ve a navigation drawer that contains some menu. In one of those items I want to display a Tab activity or let’s say view. My problem is in the replace method we should pass a Fragment and in a tabbed view you can't do it with a `Fragment` you should have an activity or a `FragmentActiviy`. Now I’m trying to found a solution to this.

Comment: "in a tabbed view you can't do it with a Fragment" -- you are welcome to use any tab solution inside of a fragment. A `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, or `FragmentTabHost`, or even the classic `TabHost` with `Views` for tabs, all work inside of a fragment. The only limitation is that if your tabs themselves will be fragments (e.g., with `FragmentTabHost`), that will give you nested fragments, and nested fragments only work on API Level 17+ or with the Android Support package's backport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that actually forbids using a ViewPager inside a Fragment, but I'd try to avoid going down that road. I fear for the UX, having both a *navigation* drawer and tab *navigation* is very confusing.

If you must do it nonetheless, you can find an example of using ViewPager on the official documentation page [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html), it is using Activity but the only main difference I see when implementing that in a Fragment is that the FragmentManager you use should be the one obtained calling [getChildFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) inside the main Fragment.